# Azure VM Communication link failure on ODBC

Tags: azure, odbc, azure-virtual-machine

I've got an Azure VM that I am trying to create an ODBC connection on using ODBC administrator. When trying to connect however it errors with

```
[SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB32 DLL][HDBODBC32]Communication link failure;- 10709 
Connection failed (RTE:[89006]System call 'connect' failed, rc=10060:A 
connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly 
respond after a period of time, or estab
```

I have tried disabling the firewall to see if that works to no avail. Also, I am unable to ping the server using the VM, or even ping google.com for that matter. But I am completely at a loss. Any help or ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you open your SQL port on Azure NSG? I suggest you could use tool to connect your SQL.

Comment: It should already be open. I am able to make other ODBC connections. Just this SAP hana one refuses. What port number is that again? I can double check.

Comment: Do you use SQL server? The default port is 1433.

Comment: SAP Hana, isn't the same as SQL Server, it uses port 30015. Which I have opened using windows firewall

Comment: You also need open port on Azure NSG. Like this screenshot https://imgur.com/a/pCEPN

Comment: I don't have access to the portal to do this. Is there anyway to do it using windows firewall with advanced security?